# Zsh completion inside quotes

Tags: autocomplete, zsh

Here is my completion function:

```
f()
{    
    reply=('ok')
}
compctl -K f c
```

Then I do

```
c
```

<kbd>tab</kbd>

```
c ok
```

Something works. Then I do <kbd>tab</kbd> after `b`

```
c ok "a b"
```

and nothing happens. I expect `a b` to be replaced with `ok` (as it does in bash).

How could I achieve it?

I really need to do completions inside quotes. Typical launch of my program looks like this: `c 'a, &b, c[d]' 'a < 1 and b == "2013"'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the use of quotes. zsh doesn't offer `ok` as a completion in your second case because it isn't anywhere close to what was already entered for that argument. The completion wouldn't be offered after `c a` either.

zsh generally assumes that what is to be completed will be somewhat related to what has already been entered, relieving the author of a completion function from needing to check for matches. You can add the `-U` option to your compctl command to tell it that the entire `$reply` list should be used, even entries which don't match.

I should also note that compctl belongs to the old zsh completion system. The new completion system is described in the [zshcompsys manpage](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html)

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not manage to get through new style completions docs. Too complicated for me