# Zsh cursor position during completion

Tags: autocomplete, zsh

Here is my completion function:

```
f()
{
    local l
    read -l l

    reply=('ok')
}
compctl -K f c
```

Then I do

```
c o
```

<kbd>tab</kbd>

```
c ok
```

Something this works. `l` equals to `c o`. Then I press <kbd>tab</kbd> before `b`:

```
c ok b
```

`l` equals to `c ok b`, great, but how can I determine that complition happened not at the end of string but before `b`? Can I get the cursor position as in bash via `COMP_POINT`?

Comment: This might be useful: https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/commit/edab1d3dbe61da7efe5f1ac0e40444b2ec9b9570

Comment: It relies on `bashcompinit` , if I use it I am stuck with other problem witch we've already solved using that approach described in question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126034/zsh-completion-inside-quotes . Resume: if I could change approach it would have, but I can not.